# How to correct identify js code in CakePHP project with PhpStorm IDE?

Tags: javascript, php, cakephp, phpstorm, cakephp-3.0

I am using Phpstorm as IDE in a CakePHP 3.0 project and the plugin CakeStorm. I would like to treat code inside script blocks as javascript code but the IDE doesnt identify with the correct syntax.

```
<?php $this->start('script') ?>
  //javascript code here ...
<?php $this->end() ?>
```

I know there is a feature called "language injection" in PhpStorm that could solve the problem but couldnt figure out a way to achieve this.

Comment: (by default) that is not possible in html context, check https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.2/language-injection-settings-generic-php.html

Comment: Doubt, really doubt that it is possible at all in PhpStorm with default functionality (unless done special processing by PHP parser/custom plugin). The only thing I can think of it to use `echo` with  HEREDOC (using `JS` as a label) in actual PHP code...

Comment: any tips for the downvote?

Answer (score 4):

However, you can do that in php context:

```
$this->start('script');
echo <<<JS 
    //javascript code here ...
JS;
$this->end();
```